# charging from power outlet or computer? to save battery lifetime

Tags: battery-life, charging, 2.1-eclair

I realized that charging my HTC Desire (Android 2.1) takes longer if connected to computer compare to power outlet.

Does it matter which method I use to charge in terms of battery life time?

Comment: I would be interested in whether there is any impact to the life of the battery based on charging using one method over the other. Any suggestions or links?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, the battery doesn't care *how* it got charged in terms of a given charge. It just takes longer when using your PC because it's getting less current from the PC than the AC charger.

Here's a [post on android forums](http://androidforums.com/htc-incredible/71443-charging-time-through-usb.html) which suggests that the current coming from the PC is significantly less than the AC charger. The forum posts list 100mA or 500mA for the PC's USB port vs. 1000mA from the AC charger; these numbers could be off but the point is correct. I also found [this](http://www.phonearena.com/htmls/Charging-an-iPhone-4-through-USB-takes-30-minutes-longer-than-using-a-wall-charger-article-a_12334.html) regarding the same phenomenon with the iPhone 4.

So using the AC charger is just a matter of whether you want the phone to charge quicker or not.

Comment: You're welcome. It was a good question, some people might use the AC charger if it's slightly faster although using a PC is more convenient at times.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct.  Charging faster will generate more heat, which affects battery life, as will charging while in use.

Comment: I totally agree to @MatthewRead I had similar experiance with my Samsung galaxy. I used to charge from my PC and my wife use to charge her phone from a direct AC adapter. The ac adapter is 1000 mA. After one year my battery lasts longer than hers. We both use the same handsets and our usage is similar. we can consider the fact that women talk much ... even then her phone gets drained of 4 hours before mine.