# Can I charge Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 from USB?

Tags: usb, charging, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Galaxy Tab is not being charged through USB Cable](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9550/galaxy-tab-is-not-being-charged-through-usb-cable)

I can't charge Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 from my USB. Is this a malfunction or intended behaviour?

I know that the mains charger supplies four times the power of a single USB port, but I'd assume the tab can at least be maintained if not charged with the 500 mA of USB.

However, when the tab is plugged in, I see a red cross over the battery icon and the phone status screen says "Discharging".

[image: Screenshot]

How do I fix it?

Comment: The most concise answer from that other question *"The Samsung Galaxy Tab has a loading current of 2A, but the USB-Specificication only allows about 400mA (or was it 500mA?) at the whole bus."* So, Tablets have bigger screens and bigger batteries, need to be given more power than average phones, and the USB spec only allows a PC to give out a (relatively) small current for USB charging.

Comment: Actually I just noticed that the tables IS slowly charged from the USB, even though the battery status+icon say that it's not. Also, the linked question refers to the previous generation tab, not the Honeycomb one, so I thought that things might've changed since the devices have fairly little in common.

Comment: Some explanations of what is going on can be found at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21144/how-much-power-does-a-galaxy-tab-10-1-charger-need-to-supply

Answer (score -1):

There's no way to charge a Honeycomb tablet by USB, sadly.

Update: Most tablets can't be charged by USB, but some can be charged by USB - an example would be the Nexus 7.

Comment: This is not true for *all* Honeycomb tablets. IMHO many of them are able to charge the battery with an standard USB cable.