# How can I make my Lenovo ThinkPad tablet charge up faster?

Tags: charging, lenovo-thinkpad-tablet

It takes a very long time (half a day) to charge up with a USB 2.0 charger plugged in the wall outlet.

Comment: How long does it take?

Comment: oh, it takes half a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Put your device to sleep mode for faster charging.
2. check o/p voltage and current of your adapter(charger) and use higher o/p current adapter(this option might produce more heat while charging so could damage your device, proper cooling while charging expected)

Answer (score 3):

The USB standard only specifies a rather low charging rate (0.5 amps), but there are well-accepted ways for devices to get a higher rate (by negotiating with the host).  See [How much power does a Galaxy Tab 10.1 charger need to supply?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21144/how-much-power-does-a-galaxy-tab-10-1-charger-need-to-supply/21158#21158) for more details (of course the specifics about the Galaxy Tab probably won't apply to your phone, but the general background info probably will).  If your tablet came with a special USB adapter, try using that to see if it charges faster.

As Sagar notes, turning as much stuff or putting the tablet in sleep mode will help recharge rates.