# Can I charge my Samsung tablet without the plug in charger? Are there any other ways?

Tags: charging

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tablet but my charger is a little broken. It only charges if I play around with it but that frustrates me. Is there any other way I can charge my tablet without wasting money? Can I plug it in an Apple computer or Dell?

Comment: As with all other devices, any USB power source should do: laptop, computer, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The charger needs to output at *least* 2A to charge.

While by default USB ports don't output that much, Asus has a bit of software called [AI Charger](http://event.asus.com/mb/2010/ai_charger/) that should let you charge off some USB ports. [Lifehacker reports it works on other motherboards](http://lifehacker.com/5993609/asus-ai-charger-quickly-charges-your-iphone-or-ipad-over-a-regular-usb-port) and some Android devices.

However in the long run, getting the charger is a *much better idea*. You can use it on other devices (like future tablets!), and you're not tricking your desktop or laptop into doing something it normally does not do.

Comment: 2A is undoubtedly preferred but it is not required. See [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/21158/11343) to a related question.

Comment: unscientifically, I've not had much luck charging my tablet off USB, though I grant I've not tried AI Charger myself despite having a compatible motherboards. I still think getting an approved, compatible charger is the *smart* thing to do here, however

Comment: One of the main advantages to USB chargers is standards-based compatibility - you can plug a phone or tablet into the USB port on your computer and it should charge without and software, settings, or modification. The amperage negotiated with that port will be lower than 2 A though ([500-1500 mA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#Charging_ports_and_accessory_charging_adapters)) which is why a dedicated 2 A wall charger works more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation, I just bought a USB wall charger. This way you can charge your IPod, tablet or whatever all from the same USB socket.

As Izzy stated in the comments, you can always just plug it into your computer as well.

- http://www.bestbuy.com/site/GoPro---USB-Wall-Charger/6608113.p?id=1218767500831&skuId=6608113

I wouldn't buy one online, just go to Walmart (or your Walmart equivalent). Almost all cell phone stores carry them as well, but they sometimes charge more for them.