# Asus Transformer slow charge

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, battery, charging, asus-eee-pad-transformer

My ASUS Transformer TF101 charges extremely slowly using the original power adapter.

**I'm trying to figure out the cause.**

Here are all my knowns:

1. The power block (wall to USB adapter) charges my mobile phone without issues
2. The power block plus ASUS cable turns on my Transformer if it is off, or wakes it up if it is sleeping (but charges extremely slowly)
3. The ASUS cable lets me MTP and all that from computer and tablet
4. I installed ICS when in April and now its running 4.0.3
5. The charger does charge, but extremely slowly both on Keyboard dock and Tablet (a few days to get to 20%)
6. It definitely has not been near water, dust, direct sunlight or particle accelerators

From this I gauge: it's not the power block or the cable, and the only change was ICS a few months back which worked okay (first update was buggy, but the next one fixed this).

*Anyone else had this or know why it could be?*

Comment: If the same adapter charges your phone without any issue it must charge the power hungry table very slowly.

Comment: Does it still charge slowly while the phone is turned off? If it is, then you might have a hardware issue, perhaps a damaged battery, you might want to bring it to the store if it's still under warranty.

Comment: I shall try a different cable, if it charges fine, it was the charger. If it doesn't then yes the battery is probably damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with the charging cable. Asus quickly swapped it over with a longer cable too.

Answer (score 2):

Charging via USB can happen at very different rates depending on what the "host" end is plugged into.  Generally the vendor-supplied wall charger is the "fastest" way, but perhaps something has gone bad with your supplied wall adapter.  You should be able to improve charging times by shutting off wifi, GPS, etc, and making sure the screen is off.

See these questions for more details on what to look for on your adapters:

- [Why is charging from computer using USB slower than using an outlet?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5262/why-is-charging-from-computer-using-usb-slower-than-using-an-outlet?lq=1)
- [Galaxy Tab is not being charged through USB Cable](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9550/galaxy-tab-is-not-being-charged-through-usb-cable)

Comment: I read randomly that the power brick needs communication from the tablet to supply the 15V it needs for charging. otherwise it will operate at 5V. So it could be the 'host' or maybe the tablet not communicating properly. thanks for your post